# how to import classes from another package in java

Tags: java, import

I have a class `Student_results` in the package `Students_Record` and I want to import that to a class in the package `Forgot`. I have:

```
package Students_Record;

public class Student_results extends javax.swing.JFrame {
```

and

```
package Forgot;
import Students_Record.Student_results;
```

It says "`package Students_Record does not exist`".

Edit.

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.2.
Both project folders are in my "NetBeans Projects" folder.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: where is `Forgot`  folder relative to `Students_Record` folder ?

Comment: First use Java naming conventions.
Make sure Student_results is in your classpath.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Both folders are in my "NetBeans Projects" folder.

Answer (score 0):

On your project `Forgot` click right -> build path -> projects. Add your project here (i.e import `Students_Record`).

Comment: There was no "build path" when I clicked on it. But when I right clicked on Libraries -> Add Project, both projects were listed there. I don't know if that's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is correct.

Possible cause

- pre-compiled import issue. 
  *[if using plain text editor like notepad then compile Students_Record first using javac and then compile class in Forgot.
  detailed ref : [Importing java classes text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694544/importing-java-classes-text-editor])

  [if using IDE like eclipse then click save all in toolbar.]*
- those packages might be in different projects. provide folder location as asked by @TheScientificMethod.
- if you are trying to import from jar then make sure of your classpath values. 
  *[if using plain text editor like notepad then set classpath value.]

  [in case of eclipse IDE, refer build path by checking Properties
  section.]*

> Note- Always follow standard programming conventions for any programming language. Correct your package, class names accordingly. 
>   Reference - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf,
>   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: Please comment why negative rating ? What is missing or incorrect ?